# JuJu 2.1.2, Some subordinate charms do not deploy after relation is built

Tags: juju

I found out some subordinate charms like ceilometer-agent and neutron-openvswitch are not working. The juju deploy ceilometer-agent and juju add-relation ceilometer-agent ceilometer are all return success. Then the juju status just show ceilometer-agent is in waiting state and never attach itself to the connected ceilometer unit. The same thing also happened to neutron-openvswitch. I tried ntp and it works properly. Can anyone help?

My juju status is following. And the ceilometer-agent is stuck at waiting with no unit.

```
Model          Controller  Cloud/Region  Version
openstack-aio  maas        maas          2.1.2.1

App               Version       Status   Scale  Charm             Store  Rev  OS      Notes
ceilometer        6.1.4         active       1  ceilometer        local   44  ubuntu
ceilometer-agent                waiting      0  ceilometer-agent  local   20  ubuntu
ceph              10.2.6        active       3  ceph              local  105  ubuntu
cinder            8.1.1         active       1  cinder            local  136  ubuntu
glance            12.0.0        active       1  glance            local  150  ubuntu
keystone          9.3.0         active       1  keystone          local    0  ubuntu
mongodb                         unknown      1  mongodb           local   30  ubuntu
percona-cluster   5.6.34-26.19  active       1  percona-cluster   local   45  ubuntu
rabbitmq-server   3.5.7         active       1  rabbitmq-server   local  150  ubuntu

Unit                Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports                                    Message
ceilometer/0*       active    idle   0/lxd/6  192.168.137.47  8777/tcp                                 Unit is ready
ceph/0*             active    idle   0        192.168.137.38                                           Unit is ready and clustered
ceph/1              active    idle   1        192.168.137.39                                           Unit is ready and clustered
ceph/2              active    idle   2        192.168.137.40                                           Unit is ready and clustered
cinder/0*           active    idle   0/lxd/4  192.168.137.45  8776/tcp                                 Unit is ready
glance/0*           active    idle   0/lxd/3  192.168.137.44  9292/tcp                                 Unit is ready
keystone/0*         active    idle   0/lxd/1  192.168.137.42  5000/tcp                                 Unit is ready
mongodb/0*          unknown   idle   0/lxd/5  192.168.137.46  27017/tcp,27019/tcp,27021/tcp,28017/tcp
percona-cluster/0*  active    idle   0/lxd/0  192.168.137.41                                           Unit is ready
rabbitmq-server/0*  active    idle   0/lxd/2  192.168.137.43  5672/tcp                                 Unit is ready

Machine  State    DNS             Inst id                                                         Series  AZ
0        started  192.168.137.38  /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-1806626a-055e-11e7-9caa-52540099c447/  xenial  default
0/lxd/0  started  192.168.137.41  juju-f34c71-0-lxd-0                                             xenial
0/lxd/1  started  192.168.137.42  juju-f34c71-0-lxd-1                                             xenial
0/lxd/2  started  192.168.137.43  juju-f34c71-0-lxd-2                                             xenial
0/lxd/3  started  192.168.137.44  juju-f34c71-0-lxd-3                                             xenial
0/lxd/4  started  192.168.137.45  juju-f34c71-0-lxd-4                                             xenial
0/lxd/5  started  192.168.137.46  juju-f34c71-0-lxd-5                                             trusty
0/lxd/6  started  192.168.137.47  juju-f34c71-0-lxd-6                                             xenial
1        started  192.168.137.39  /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-19f3631a-07c1-11e7-994c-52540099c447/  xenial  default
2        started  192.168.137.40  /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-10c500c6-102e-11e7-aa5c-52540099c447/  xenial  default

Relation            Provides         Consumes          Type
cluster             ceilometer       ceilometer        peer
ceilometer-service  ceilometer       ceilometer-agent  regular
identity-service    ceilometer       keystone          regular
database            ceilometer       mongodb           regular
amqp                ceilometer       rabbitmq-server   regular
mon                 ceph             ceph              peer
ceph                ceph             cinder            regular
cluster             cinder           cinder            peer
image-service       cinder           glance            regular
identity-service    cinder           keystone          regular
shared-db           cinder           percona-cluster   regular
amqp                cinder           rabbitmq-server   regular
cluster             glance           glance            peer
identity-service    glance           keystone          regular
shared-db           glance           percona-cluster   regular
cluster             keystone         keystone          peer
shared-db           keystone         percona-cluster   regular
replica-set         mongodb          mongodb           peer
cluster             percona-cluster  percona-cluster   peer
cluster             rabbitmq-server  rabbitmq-server   peer
```

Comment: can you share the complete output of 'juju status'? Are you sure, you're adding the relation between the charms in your bundle.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I add relation and charms properly. I destroyed the model and am trying to fall back to JuJu 1. Will rebuild the juju 2 environment and post the juju status later today.